# Can't fire iron-select event on paper-listbox

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am trying to fire a simple listen function on an iron-select event based on the selection of a value in a paper-dropdown-menu.

Here is my HTML's head

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>My App</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="./main.scss" />
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/neon-animation/neon-animation.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/neon-animation/web-animations.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/paper-item/paper-item.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/paper-input/paper-input.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/iron-icon/iron-icon.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/iron-icons/iron-icons.html"/>
</head>
```

My HTML's body

```
<div class="assign-country">
  <paper-dropdown-menu on-iron-select="listen" label="Country">
    <paper-listbox on-iron-select="listen" slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content" selected="1">
      <paper-item>France</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Germany</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Spain</paper-item>
      <paper-item>England</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
</div>
```

And my JS function

```
function listen () {
  console.log('coucou');
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit better what you need to do?

Comment: When user selects a value in the dropdown menu, I want to call the function "listen". Can't get any console.log in my console as it is.

Comment: Polymer 2, right? Is your `listen()` function inside your custom element (your class that extends `Polymer.Element`)? If so, why is `function` in front. That's not required (but I dunno if it breaks anything).

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this not using Polymer, only web components :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on-EVENTNAME="METHODNAME"` is [Polymer-specific syntax to setup an annotated event listener](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners), but these annotations only work inside a Polymer template (inside a [`<dom-module>`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.DomModule) or [`<dom-bind>`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.DomBind)).

Given the example code and your [intention to avoid Polymer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634716/cant-fire-iron-select-event-on-paper-listbox#comment90235769_51634716), you should setup the event listeners manually with a reference to the element. The same `iron-select` event fires on both `<paper-dropdown-menu>` and the inner `<paper-listbox>`, so you only need to listen to the `iron-select` event on one of them. Here's one solution:

1. Assign an ID to `<paper-dropdown-menu>` so that it can easily be referenced in JavaScript (with [`Document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)).

   ```
   <paper-dropdown-menu id="mydropdown">
   ```
2. Add an event listener (with [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) to the `<paper-dropdown-menu>` reference:

   ```
   const dropdown = document.getElementById('mydropdown');
   dropdown.addEventListener('iron-select', e => listen(e));
   ```

```js
const dropdown = document.getElementById('mydropdown');
dropdown.addEventListener('iron-select', e => listen(e));

function listen(e) {
  console.log('iron-select', e);
  document.getElementById('output').innerText = e.detail.item.innerText;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/web-animations.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-dropdown-menu id="mydropdown" label="Country">
    <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content" selected="1">
      <paper-item>France</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Germany</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Spain</paper-item>
      <paper-item>England</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
  <pre id="output"></pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if it is what you are trying to achieve:

```js
$('paper-item').click(function(){
   console.log($(this).text());
    })
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>My App</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="./main.scss" />

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
 
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/neon-animation/neon-animation.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/neon-animation/web-animations.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/paper-item/paper-item.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/paper-input/paper-input.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/iron-icon/iron-icon.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/iron-icons/iron-icons.html"/>
</head>

<div class="assign-country">
  <paper-dropdown-menu on-iron-select="listen" label="Country">
    <paper-listbox on-iron-select="listen" slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content" selected="1">
      <paper-item name="france">France</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Germany</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Spain</paper-item>
      <paper-item>England</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, this is somewhat my last solution but before I would like to understand the use of polymer event listener "iron-select". Why can't it work as it says in the doc [https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-listbox/elements/paper-listbox#event-iron-select] ?